# Unable to get child elements in div in xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following code, which I am trying to extract 'Washington square - USA' part from it.
It is located inside `div/p/strong` but div has a class as you can see.

below is the relevant code, or you can see the [entire code in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0eHL6Sf4)

```
<div class="content clearfix">
<p><strong>Washington square - USA<br>
</strong></p>
<p><strong>2 studios for rent – env. 54m2</strong></p>
<p><strong>near public transport</strong></p>
<p>Studios comprise</p>
<ul>
<li>A kitchen</li>
<li>A bedroom</li>
<li>Tolilet with bathtab</li>
</ul>
<p>Visitation date (not yet known)</p>
<p>To rent from 1st april</p>
<p>(Current owner : Ben)</p>
<p><strong>For more details visit: http://example.com<br>
</strong></p>
<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
    </div>
```

So, I have tried the following ways to get the content

```
//div[contains(@class, "content")]/p/strong
//div[contains(@class, "content") and contains(@class,  'clearfix')]/p/strong
//div[contains(@class, "content") and contains(@class,  'clearfix')]/p[1]/strong
//string(div[contains(@class, "content") and contains(@class,  'clearfix')]/p/strong)
//div[contains(@class, "content") and contains(@class,  'clearfix')]/p/strong/text()
```

But none of the return the desired output

EDIT

I am using this code to parse the page

```
$document = new \DOMDocument(); 
$document->loadHTMLFile($htmlUrl);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "content")]//p[1]') as  $div) {
    # Also tried with these
    //div[contains(@class, "content")]/p/strong
    //div[contains(@class, "content") and contains(@class,  'clearfix')]/p/strong
    //div[contains(@class, "content") and contains(@class,  'clearfix')]/p[1]/strong
    //string(div[contains(@class, "content") and contains(@class,  'clearfix')]/p/strong)
    //div[contains(@class, "content") and contains(@class,  'clearfix')]/p/strong/text()
    var_dump($div);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP code or XPATH in your pastebin reference.

Comment: The XPaths work. Please show the code where you apply them, the result you get, and what you expected.

Comment: Use `$div->textContent` as in [this example](https://eval.in/748195).

Comment: @trincot for some reason, I don't get the same result I get all the text inside the div

Comment: Then what is different in your code and/or HTML? As you can see in the link I provided, it can work with `$div->textContent`.

Comment: I showed my code already, this problem is also strange for me. Do you think the page is injecting something after the browser renders the html? I can't understand it

Comment: How could I know? You can check the DOM via the console and see what is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Element:
//div[contains(@class, 'content')]/p[1]/strong

then take textContent

or Text:
//div[contains(@class, 'content')]/p[1]/strong/text()

and your xml is not well-formed: because of < br >